# Display busy indicator while controller action work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

I have a problem right now and I hope you can help me.

My problem is that I have a Controller in which I generate a file as byteArray (without saving it on hard disk), which I return to download.
These action takes up to 5-6 seconds until its generated. Now I would like to display a busy indicator for the user, but I don't know, how can I identify, when my controller is done!?

Here is my code:

This is the code to call my Controller action in my "View.cshtml":

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DownloadAnalysis", "Analysis")" title="Get analysis file"><span class="fa fa-bar-chart"></span></a>
```

This my Controller code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadAnalysis()
{
        var response = StartAnalysis();

        if (response.AnalysisByteArray != null && response.AnalysisByteArray.Length > 0)
        {
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = response.FileName,
                Inline = false,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return File(response.AnalysisByteArray , "text/csv");
        }

        return null;
}
```

I thank you in advance for your help!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the anchor tag use a button and onclick event to call the controller.
your html should be like

```
<button title="Get analysis file" onclick="getFile()"><span class="fa fa-bar-chart"></span></button>
```

and in JavaScript use window.location to call the controller action

```
<script>
    function getFile(){
         //here you can add script to change cursor to progress of add some html element to show loading.
         window.location.href = '/Analysis/DownloadAnalysis/';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer! In the "getFile"-Function I can set for e.g. a busy indicator, but how do I know, when the Action is done and I can hide the busy indicator?

Comment: I'm not sure about the file type if the file will be opened in the browser then you current html page will automatically get hide.

Comment: I'm not sure about the file type if the file will be opened in the browser then you current html page will automatically get hide.